# URL for PDF file in a static resource zip file

Tags: static-resources

Can I get the URL for a PDF file in a static resource zip file?  The file I am trying to access is in a static resource called BRLShort on https://niimbl.my.site.com. The PDF name is brl.pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works to call a pdf from a zipped static resource.

https://niimbl.my.site.com/resource/BRLShort/brl.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access the file using the general resource URL of `/resource/BRLShort/brl.pdf`.

Alternatively, if you have access to formulas (fields, Visualforce, etc):

```
{!URLFOR($Resource.BRLShort, null)}/brl.pdf
```

Or for LWC:

```
import BRLShort from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/BRLShort';

var pdfFileUrl = BRLShort+'/brl.pdf';
```